# Key-based authentication such that they have access only to /home folder

Tags: ssh, permissions, centos

I have a Linux CentOO web server in which I have multiple web sites. I have 5 website programmers now doing the coding for all the sites.

How can I provide a key-based authentication for the programmers in such a way that they have access only to /home folder? They should be able to access only all the files inside /home and able to modify it.

Comment: Just remember to add the distro of Linux you guys use.

Comment: Server is CentOS

Answer (score 2):

I think, you are looking for CHROOTING.

With the release of OpenSSH 4.9p1, you no longer have to rely on third-party hacks or complicated chroot setups to confine users to their home directories or give them access to SFTP services

Chroot users with OpenSSH is an easier way to confine users to their home directories

Have a look at this article
[Chroot users with openssh](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/chroot-users-with-openssh-an-easier-way-to-confine-users-to-their-home-directories/)

Comment: Actually my server is cPanel server in which all the sites comes under /home directory. If I could give access to my developer inside /home folder, he would be able to do edit all the sites easily rather than having separate password for each site (eg : /home/site1 or /home/site2).

Comment: Well am not sure about this as am not an expert in cpanel. Can you apply stickybit ? A Sticky bit is a permission bit that is set on a file or a directory that lets only the owner of the file/directory or the root user to delete or rename the file. No other user is given privileges to delete the file created by some other user.